# BluetoothGattCharacteristic.value returns empty value

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to parse a value of a BluetoothGattCharacteristic to another activity. I can read the characteristic successfully, but then the value it gives me is empty...

I am trying to read the device name. In another BLE app (nRF connect) can I see the characteristic and its value. Can someone help me, what am I doing wrong?

This method loops and logs the services found with its characteristics:

```
private void displayGattServices(List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices) {
    //Check if there is any gatt services. If not, return.
    if (gattServices == null) return;

    // Loop through available GATT Services.
    for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {
        Log.i(TAG, "SERVICE FOUND: " + gattService.getUuid().toString());
        //Loop through available characteristics for each service
        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattService.getCharacteristics()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "  CHAR. FOUND: " + gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString());
        }
    }

    //****************************************
    // CONNECTION PROCESS FINISHED!
    //****************************************
    Log.i(TAG, "*************************************");
    Log.i(TAG, "CONNECTION COMPLETED SUCCESFULLY");
    Log.i(TAG, "*************************************");

    goToDisplayBleServicesActivityOnListItemClick();
}
```

goToDisplayBleServiceActivityOnListItemClick():

```
private void goToDisplayBleServicesActivityOnListItemClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, displayBleServicesActivity.class);
    BluetoothGattService selectedService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic selectedCharacteristic = selectedService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
    if (mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(selectedCharacteristic)) {
        intent.putExtra("READ_CHAR", selectedCharacteristic.getValue().toString());
    } else {
        intent.putExtra("READ_CHAR", "It did not work out");
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt#readCharacteristic(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic) it says:

> This is an asynchronous operation. The result of the read operation is reported by the `BluetoothGattCallback#onCharacteristicRead` callback.

So you must override the `onCharacteristicRead` callback. Inside that one you can get the value.

Comment: Oh nice, this worked indeed. Forgot to put the read in the Override method. But how can I send the value to another activity in my intent.putExtra method?